# Xamarin Forms iOS Launch Screen Image Position

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Studio and have a Xamarin Forms project for both iOS and Android.  For my iOS app, I have created a xib file for my launch screen.  I have added an image view and and an image to that view. Every time I change the simulated metrics size (in Xcode) the image repositions itself (same if I run on different sized iDevices).  How do I correct this?  I want the image always centered vertically and about 1/3 of the way down from the top.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [on the Xamarin Launch Screen Guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/#storyboard), if you use a `Universal Launch Screen` and click `Enable Size Classes`, then your `Launch Screen` will automatically scale dependent on the screen size.

I also personally found, that I needed to use `Center Constraints` for my ´Views` as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/#Center_Constraints). As mentioned in the guide:

> If you choose a horizontal drop area, the constraint will be based on
>   centerX

Hope this helps.

---

### Edit

You may need to open the .xib file in XCode as there is an issue opening Universal Screens in in Xamarin Studio.

Additionally, to enable `Size classes` in XCode, simply follow [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html).

Comment: Looks promising but the storyboard file won't open in Xamarin Studio for me  - just hangs with spinning wait cursor.  I will Google this issue shortly.  Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you will probably need to use XCode to open the .xib file. There is an issue with loading the universal launch screens in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't find enable size classes.

Comment: Ah right, forgot to mention it's different in XCode. Please see [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) from Apple's developer portal.

Comment: Latest version of XS 9.8 allows editing of the storyboard and the first link above got me "centered".  My storyboard consists of 3 items, top to bottom, an image view with image, label1, label2.  At runtime, label1 is above the image/imageview, odd?  Thanks for your help.